# Differences between 死ぬ{しぬ}, 他界する{たかいする} and 亡くなる{なくなる}?

Tags: words, usage, synonyms

What are the differences between 死ぬ{しぬ}, 他界する{たかいする} and 亡くなる{なくなる}?

Comment: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/thsrs/4551/m0u/%E6%AD%BB%E3%81%AC/

Comment: Kicked the bucket, bought the farm, pushing up daisies, bit the dust, etc.

Answer (score 8):

From my personal experience,

**「亡くなる」** is the most neutral word.

```
「先生のお父さんはがんで亡くなられたよ」 - "Our teacher's father died from cancer"
```

**「死ぬ」** is a strong word that is usually avoided by polite people, but is used to express emphasis or to deliberately offend. It can also be used to talk about animals.

```
「勝手に死ね！」 - Literally, "Die on your own!", but is very strong and rude.
「あのセミが死んでいるよ」 - "That cicada is dead"
```

**「他界する」** is a polite word (often used on television) to express the idea that someone has "left this world".

```
「美紀ちゃんは13才という若さで他界した」 - "Miki-chan passed away at the tender age of 13"
```

Answer (score 3):

死ぬ is the general, neutral term for "to die". 他界する assumes particular belief, namely that the person/animal goes to the afterworld. 亡くなる is euphemism.

Answer (score 1):

死亡する　is also used in place of 死ぬ because the latter is too strong a word. It's used in news articles, announcements, and I think has a slightly official and impersonal feel to it.