# What is the difference between these sentences?

Tags: word-choice, nuances, wago-and-kango

I was trying to write "Half of the population will die" in Google Translate. I wrote：

「人口の半分は死にます。」

But Google decided this was better:

「人口の半分が死亡します。」

Are these just different ways to write the same sentence, or is using the noun and する verb better for this sentence?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18219/differences-between-死ぬしぬ-他界するたかいする-and-亡くなるなくなる

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither is better than the other per se, but there is a clear difference in formality. As usual, the kango version (死亡) is more formal, whereas the wago version (死ぬ) is more common in casual speech.

See questions tagged with [wago-and-kango](/questions/tagged/wago-and-kango).